# Want to convert it in build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I am very new to gradle, so I need help.

I have a simple bat file with below code.

```
set cp=%CLASSPATH%;.
set cp=%cp%;.\abc.jar
set cp=%cp%;.\xyz.jar


javac -d classes -cp "%cp%" com\myproject\convert\plugins\plugin1\MyPlugin1.java

jar -cvf CustomPlugin1.jar -C classes .
```

Now i want to convert this bat file in build.gradle file.
Like plugin1 I have total 10 plugins to build, but i want to build separate jar for each plugin. And every plugin includes a single java file. SO I guess I have to define 10 different tasks in gradle, as i want a provision to build any single plugin whenever required.

So how can I achieve it in an easy way ?

Comment: If you have 10 different artefacts, all built from classes that are independant from each other, and built independantly, you should have 10 different gradle projects.

Comment: Just for a single java file I don't want to make 10 different projects and build.gradle files. Cant I do it in 1 build.gradle file with 10 different tasks ?

Comment: Basically gradle is flexible enough to handle it, but.. should it? What are the differences between artifacts?

Comment: Difference is just a different java file of different plugin. Thats it. So how can I achieve it?